# Why Goku SSJ4 transformation has yellow eyes and Vegeta SSJ4 tranformation has blue eyes?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-gt, dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball GT, Goku SSJ4 transformation has yellow eyes.

[image]

But Vegeta SSJ4 transformation has blue eyes

[image]

has there ever been an explanation why this is so? Do these transformations have anything different or something?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. You could compare it to asking why Goku is taller than Vegeta or why Vegeta Voice is deeper than Goku's.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 Uh, no.  Super Saiyan transformations typically have uniform appearances.  For example, SS! changes eye eye color to solid blue IIRC.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser The colors have varied multiple times depending on the animators. So it comes down to design. It has nothing to do with the transformation or it being exclusive to a Saiyan. The only mention of the eyes was recently when Goku unlocked the Ultra Instinct Omen/ Mastered Ultra Instinct transformations and much more detail has been given to the eyes.

Comment: The original color is supposed to be red. There are instances when their eyes are colored green, yellow etc. It comes down to design. Just like Goku and Vegeta appear a lot skinnier now. Also, Vegeta seems to be taller in comparison to Goku than he was before. All these vary based on the staff for the particular series/ episode. This isn't reddit. Questions and answers are supposed to be factual not opinionated.